# I want to use matplotlib.pyplot module on Idle 3.4 "Python"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

I want to use plt.plot(x,y) and plt.show().

When I use 'Idle.exe', I can use matplotlib.pyplot and numpy.

However, when I use 'IDLE (Python 3.4 GUI - 32 bit)', I cannot use matplotlib.pyplot and numpy.

I managed to solve the problem of numpy module, but I couldn't to matplotlib...

For reference, my OS is Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is simply that it requires the module dateutil as seen in the output.

Just run in your command line,`pip install dateutil`

Or if that doesn't work, `pip install python-dateutil`